# JacksonXml - How Unmarshal/Deserialize the last commented line in XML file

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-deserialization, jackson-modules

I have XML file where the last line is a commented text and contains unique ID XXX. **The goal is a deserialize the comment value** of a property.

```
<countries>
  <code>AD<code/>
  <code>AE<code/>     
</countries>
<!-- RUID: [XXXX] -->
```

Expected class structure

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "countries")
public class CountriesRS {
    String RUID; // the property to store velue from  <!-- RUID: [XXXX] -->
    List<String> code;
}
```

Code to read value

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

CountriesRS rs = xmlMapper.readValue(detailsString, CountriesRS.class);
```

How can I configure **XmlMapper** to do this?

I have use **jackson-dataformat-xml** version 2.8

Comment: I am not an expect on xml deserialization with jackson, but I am pretty sure you'll need to hack it yourself. Take the file or the input that you get, parse the comments and build your rest of the xml with the `XmlMapper`, and set at the end the what parsing you did in your CountriesRS object

Comment: If you have any helpful examples how to customize XmlMapper, please share with me.